# Which of these services can I safely disable?

Tags: performance, ram

Before install stuff on my server I wanted to trim down unnecessary services. etc.

**Here's the top:**

```
        615 ubuntu    20   0 26948 7384 1648 S  0.0  1.2   0:00.39 bash                                                                                                                                         
  732 ubuntu    20   0 28188 4144 1032 S  0.5  0.7   0:00.77 screen                                                                                                                                       
  811 ubuntu    20   0 23452 3952 1712 S  0.0  0.7   0:00.20 bash                                                                                                                                         
  587 root      20   0 73080 3440 2676 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.01 sshd                                                                                                                                         
  463 root      20   0 49684 2784 2208 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 sshd                                                                                                                                         
    1 root      20   0 24052 2132 1316 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.26 init                                                                                                                                         
  614 ubuntu    20   0 73080 1560  800 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.23 sshd                                                                                                                                         
  469 syslog    20   0 52728 1480 1088 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.06 rsyslogd                                                                                                                                     
 1539 ubuntu    20   0 21436 1296  988 R  0.5  0.2   0:00.45 top                                                                                                                                          
  713 ubuntu    20   0 25456 1172  936 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.01 screen                                                                                                                                       
  223 root      20   0 21320 1148  764 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.03 udevd                                                                                                                                        
  480 messageb  20   0 24152  968  700 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.04 dbus-daemon                                                                                                                                  
  528 root      20   0 18976  892  696 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 cron                                                                                                                                         
  307 root      20   0 21316  732  336 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd                                                                                                                                        
  298 root      20   0 21316  684  304 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 udevd                                                                                                                                        
  521 root      20   0  4180  640  536 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty                                                                                                                                        
  524 root      20   0  4180  640  536 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty                                                                                                                                        
  220 root      20   0 17096  636  452 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.04 upstart-udev-br                                                                                                                              
  513 root      20   0  4180  636  536 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty                                                                                                                                        
  518 root      20   0  4180  636  536 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty                                                                                                                                        
  522 root      20   0  4180  636  536 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty                                                                                                                                        
  581 root      20   0  4180  636  536 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 getty                                                                                                                                        
  384 root      20   0  7124  604  120 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 dhclient3                                                                                                                                    
  339 root      20   0 15048  392  196 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 upstart-socket-                                                                                                                              
  529 daemon    20   0 16776  376  220 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 atd                                                                                                                                          
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                     
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                                  
    4 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0                                                                                                                                  
    5 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kworker/u:0                                                                                                                                  
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                                                                                  
    7 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset                                                                                                                                       
    8 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper                                                                                                                                      
    9 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                                                                                                        
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xenwatch                                                                                                                                     
   11 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.15 xenbus                                                                                                                                       
   12 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 sync_supers                                                                                                                                  
   13 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bdi-default                                                                                                                                  
   14 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd                                                                                                                                  
   15 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd                                                                                                                                      
   16 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff                                                                                                                                      
   17 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd                                                                                                                                        
   18 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md                                                                                                                                           
   19 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd                                                                                                                                   
   20 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/u:1                                                                                                                                  
   21 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.5  0.0   0:00.11 kworker/0:1                                                                                                                                  
   22 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kswapd0                                                                                                                                      
   23 root      25   5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd                                                                                                                                         
   24 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 fsnotify_mark                                                                                                                                
   25 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ecryptfs-kthrea
```

What can I safely disable and how?

Answer (score 2):

There's probably nothing you don't need. If you don't need ssh access to this system you can remove `openssh-server`. If you have a static IP, you can configure it in `/etc/network/interfaces` and `dhclient3` will no longer be started.

Everything in the list with PID <= 25 is a kernel thread anyway (except of course for PID 1, which is always `init`).